# Wordpress Plugin - Open Pages Inside Admin Panel

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, plugins

I am making a plugin.  The plugin has pages that access a database, add, edit and delete records, call stored procedures etc.  I have gotten as far as creating the plugin, and adding menus and submenus to the admin panel and having those menu links open in the admin panel.  These are pages that handle the adding, deleting and editing of records in the database.  Some of these pages have a link that would pass an id for example to another page in order to edit a record.

Those pages that are used in the admin panel of my plugin, that link to other admin pages for my plugin, do not open in the admin panel, they open outside of it.  How can I create links in my plugin pages to stay inside of the admin panel of wordpress?

To clarify, I am able to add menu items that load pages in the admin panel.  Maybe this screen shot will explain.  So how can I open pages inside the admin panel?

[image]

Comment: Please clarify what you're trying to do. Are you importing a non-WP site into WP? You need to be far more specific if you are to get useful answers to this question.

Comment: Editing my original post.

Comment: not sure why I am getting negative points.

Comment: It's possible you're getting downvoted because the answer to your question is documented very clearly in the WordPress Codex.

Comment: Actually he's getting voted down because people misunderstand the question, because he didn't really explain it well.  I think he's talking about sub-pages.

Answer (score 0):

In order to display your plugin's administrative UI within the framework of the WordPress dashboard you need to follow quite a few WordPress conventions.

The first is to write code for each administrative panel in a separate function. Each of these functions (one per admin panel in your plugin) must display the panel's HTML elements in a `<div>` object, allowing WordPress itself to wrap your divs in the dashboard display.

The next is to write a menu-building function for your plugin's dashboard menus, and then register that function with the admin_menu action hook. This menu-building function will contain references to your functions to display administrative panels.

Here is a writeup on the topic. http://codex.wordpress.org/Administration_Menus

Comment: Thanks for point in me to the codex.  I have already been to that page which is where I learned about adding menus and submenus.  My question is more specific; how do links inside of my admin page open inside of the admin window?  I added a screen shot to my question.  I hope that helps clarify, I am really stuck.